# Web Application Installer package for Installation on (LWM)AMP

Tags: php, installation

I am looking for a product similar to bit rock's Web Stack's where you can install an application along with a web application bundled together so it is simple point and click for an end user.

I am trying to find a cross platform installer. (Mac, Windows, and Linux)

Any ideas?

Here is the information for a web stack from bit rock:

http://bitnami.org/learn_more

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand is you want something to run your PHP scripts as applications, have you tried Adobe AIR ?

IF you are talking about something else, please post some links for your example because I can't find any information about that product..

Comment: I have posted information about a stack. I basically want to make an installer for a php application that installs apache, mysql, and php + application and configures it. this is so a user needs to know nothing about web servers and databases.

Comment: something like what xampp, lampp, and other bundles offer,PLUS, your web script, I'm sorry, I haven't seen this before and I hope to see someone answer this, Really interested in this idea !